# Renderizar api do ibge em um select com laravel + livewire + alpineJs

Tags: laravel

Eu tenho um select que sera preenchido com os estados vindo de uma api do ibge ele não mostra nenhum erro no console, mas eu ja verifiquei na network do navegador que esta chegando os dados corretamente
codigo a seguir:

html

```
 <div class="col-4 mb-3" x-data="uf">
        <label class="form-label">Estado:</label>
        <select class="form-control" wire:model='state'>
            <option value="" selected>Selecione...</option>
             <template x-for="state in states" :key="state.id">
                 <option x-bind:value="state.sigla" x-text="state.nome"></option>
              </template>
         </select>
     </div>
```

js

```
<script>
     document.addEventListener('alpine:init', async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados');
                const data = await response.json();
    
                Alpine.data('uf', {
                    states: data
                });
    
                 
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erro ao obter os dados:', error);
            }
    
        });

</script>
```

Comment: qual é o problema, na sua pergunta não diz o que está ocorrendo, se tem algum erro etc ???

Comment: `wire:model='state'` não seria `wire:model='uf'` não tem código errado?

Comment: ele não renderiza os dados porem nao dispara nenhum erro no console e na aba de network ele ta recebendo os dados da api corretamente

Comment: esse uf e do componenete do livewire pra pegar dados para o back nao tem a ver com o alpineJs

Comment: dentro do alpine tem um método inicializador `init() {}` como demostrado nesse link https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init ( no final tem o exemplo) aquele código tem que ser chamado dentro do alpinejs!

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.